# Are there any good academic articles about Feb 2018 correction?

Tags: research

Question pretty self-explanatory – I want to see if there have been any reputable papers released regarding the 2018 February market correction, since it happened quite recently.

I do not need the paper to necessarily focus just on this event – any papers on financial models being tested in regards to this event or similar would work. Although if the articles are on options and/or the VIX index that would be ideal.

Thank you.

Comment: Not fully academic but this report by BIS may be of interest: https://www.bis.org/publ/qtrpdf/r_qt1803t.htm

Comment: @Magicisinthechain thank you